# Can ignore group of result if a row does not past a filter

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have the next query

```
SELECT id, type FROM clients WHERE 1 GROUP BY id, type

+----+------+
| id | type |
+------+----+
|  1 |    1 |
|  1 |    2 |
|  1 |    3 |
|  2 |    2 |
|  2 |    3 |
+----+------+
```

But i want to ignore the id "1", because this have a type 1, so, in this case, i just want to have the id "2"

Can anyone help me, thanks

Comment: Your question seems somewhat cryptically phrased to me, and I am usually pretty good at guessing what people are looking for. What is wrong with `WHERE id <> 1`? _You have `type` 2 and 3 (in the data) as well, so it sounds like you shouldn't have `id` 2 either._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT id, type 
FROM clients AS c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM clients AS c2
                  WHERE c1.id = c2.id AND c2.type = 1)
```

**Output:**

```
+----+------+
| id | type |
+----+------+
|  2 |    2 |
|  2 |    3 |
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

a little bit different syntax:

```
SELECT distinct id, type
FROM clients
WHERE id not in (select distinct id from clients where type=1)
```